# Macintosh SE PSU Servicing?

Tags: mac, power-supply, hardware-failure, mac-se

First thing's first: I take full responsibility for any injury sustained while servicing a PSU. Any advice offered here is to be considered purely subjective.

I own a Macintosh SE, which was functioning fine until the last time I used it. It booted up fine, and worked for 5 minutes, until smoke began pouring out of it. The smoke was accompanied by an electrical buzzing noise. I immediately switched off the system and pulled out the power cable. As it was functioning fine (in terms of the computer itself not halting), I think only the PSU fried.

Ideally, I'd replace the PSU. But, since it was manufactured in the 80's, it's not that easy to replace. I could probably buy another SE off ebay to harvest parts from, but it will be just as old and prone to exploding. So, why not service the PSU itself, removing damaged/old components to replace them with new equivalents?

My questions are: is a PSU even serviceable? What precautions do I have to take? Do I have to discharge certain components first? Just... how do you service a PSU in the first place?

Comment: This question pertains to computer hardware so it's not off-topic here on SuperUser, but you'll probably find a better audience for this kind of question on electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really recommend repairing this yourself unless you have some experience dealing with high voltage and/or CRTs. If you go ahead with this, there are several things you'll need to worry about:

- The picture tube anode carries a very high voltage, and can retain it after the computer is powered off. >here's a bleeder resistor that-s *supposed* to drain this, but you should always assume that's failed. You can find advice about safely discharging this in a number of places (see links below), but they all tend to conflict. I'll stay out of the argument, except to note that if you get it too far wrong, there's a slight possibility you might kill yourself. Thus my reservations about recommending this...
- There's also a risk of breaking the picture tube. It has a small curcuit board on the back of the tube, and if you bump that wrong it'll snap the end of the tube. It's safest to remove that early in the process (but after making sure the anode's discharged) by pulling it *straight* back off the picture tube. Be similarly careful when reassembling it.
- To even open the case, you'll need a long-shafted Torx T-15 screwdriver to get at the screws under the handle.
- The PSU is in a metal case that's sort of trapped between the analog (video) board and the metal frame. There's a certain amount of gentle wiggling involved in getting everything to come apart.
- It's also slightly possible that some of the capacitors inside the power supply will hold a charge, but I don't remember where they are (and IIRC Apple used a couple of different PSU designs, so it'd be different between them anyway).

As for the actual repair... it'll depend entirely on what you find when you open it up. My guess would be blown capacitor(s), but that's really just a guess.

Anyway, here are some links that describe takeapart, discharge, etc: http://www.ccadams.org/se/repair.html (ignore the "Classic Mac repair notes, they're about older models) and http://www.biwa.ne.jp/~shamada/fullmac/repairEng.html.